$E/F$ is normal iff $E$ is a splitting field of some $f(x)\in F[x]$, is it always valid?
This result is proven and well known for finite field extensions, however, consider the question:
Let $F$ be a field and let $E/F$ be a finite extension. Suppose that $\alpha_1, \dots , \alpha_k \in E$ are chosen such that $E = F(\alpha_1, \dots , \alpha_k)$. We set $f_i
:= \min(\alpha_i, F)$ for $1 \leq i \leq k$, and $f(x) := f_1(x)\dots f_k(x)$. Let $K/E$ denote the splitting extension of $f(x)$. Note $f \in F[x]$ hence $f \in E[x]$. Prove that $K/F$ is a normal extension.
To which we can answer;
$K$ is a splitting field of $f(x)\in F[x]$ hence $K/F$ is normal.
My question :
Is this an incorrect argument? And why?
Some context: What is the definition of a splitting extension? Is it the same as splitting field?

"The splitting extension of $f(x)$" is indeed the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $E$.

I would say the argument is correct but incomplete. You need to prove that $K$ is the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $F$, not just assert it. It's defined as the splitting field of $f$ over $E$. In general, if $E/F$ is an extension, $f(x)\in F[x]$, and you take the splitting field of $f$ over $E$, the resulting field need not be the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $F$ (e.g., $F=\mathbb{Q}$, $E=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$, $f(x)=x^2-2$; the splitting field of $f$ over $E$ is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$, which is not the splitting field of $f$ over $F$).

In your example, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$ is the splitting field of $(x^2-2)(x^2-3)$ hence normal.
Can you please point out where my argument is incomplete? This means the result I am using is false, doesn't it?

It is the splitting field of a polynomial that is different from $f(x)$; so it is not a splitting field of $f(x)$ over $F$. The point is that in the situation you have, you can't just say "it's the splitting field over $F$". You need to prove that it is. Just because the polynomial splits over $K$ does not mean you have the splitting field of $F$.

I replied to show how would I answer your example, but I am interested in the original post, where did I make a mistake? Can you please clarify what you mean by splitting field over F? I know the definition of a splitting field of a polynomial.
Do you agree with this theorem: $E$ is a splitting field of $f(x)\in F[x]$ is equivalent to $E/F$ is normal ?

I am having a language syntax problem here, you may consider that I do not know anything about the math, and just explain where the reasoning or definition that I used is incorrect?

I do not understand what you are talking about. I said, two months ago that your argument was "correct but incomplete" and said  why. I repeated why half an hour ago. But you ask me to tell you why?  As to you rnew questions: No, it is nonsense to say that "$E$ is a splitting field of $f(x)\in F[x]$" is equivalent to "$E/F$ is normal". First, because your $f$ is unquantified, hence must be taken to be fixed. So if I take a particular polynomial $f(x)$, (cont)

(cont) your statement would be claiming that the only normal extension is the one that is a splitting field of that polynomial. That is not correct. What is correct is that "$E$ is a normal extension of $F$" is equivalen to "there exists a set of polynomials ${f_i}_{i\in I}$ in $F[x]$ such that $E$ is the splitting field over $F$ of the family."  The polynomials depend on $E$.   You can't just say "splitting field". You need to say "splitting field" over what. The field $E$ is the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $F$ if and only if (cont)

(cont) (1) $f(x)\in F[x]$; (2) $E$ is an extension of $F$; (3) $f(x)$ splits over $E$; and (4) $E$ is generated over $F$ by  the roots of $f(x)$ in $E$.  For a family ${f_i}$, $E$ is the splitting field of the family if and only if (1) ever $f_i$ lies in $F[x]$; (2) $E$ is an extension of $F$; (3) each and every $f_i$ splits over $E$; and (4) $E$ is generated over $F$ by the set of roots of all $f_i$ that are in $E$.

I appreciate this discussion, but I still don't understand the problem. Here is a claim, please tell me if it is true or not, for the record this can be found in some lecture notes, I can share the proof from these notes; for any field $F$ and $E$ an extension of $F$, if $E$ is a splitting field of some polynomial $f\in F[x]$ (i.e. there exists a polynomial which splits over $E$ and $E$ is contained in every other field containing $E$ over which $f$ splits) then $E$ is normal over $F$, the converse also holds.

To start clarifying please, do you agree with this claim or not?
I take it that when you say splitting of $f$ over $F$ you just mean that $f\in F[x]$ (but the polynomial is still the same object)

"Do you agree with this claim". You've made lots of claims, and this comment thread is much too long. I no longer know what you think you are talking about. I believe I have answered your questions multiple times each, but you clearly disagree. As such, we are not communicating effectively. I'm out.
